# Desmos-like visual equation editor interface that can export expressions into LaTeX

Tags: equations, editors

Although somewhat similar questions have been asked in the past on this forum (links below), the answers were from a few years back and not too satisfactory, so I want to bring up this question again to see if ya'll know any new available options have popped up since.

My question is, is there any user-friendly point-and-click GUI / visual math equation editor like the online graphing software [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) or Microsoft Word's equation editor, but with the additional functionality of exporting expressions into LaTex code (which these two don't)? For those who are not familiar with these two tools, they allow you to enter an algebraic expression without knowing LaTex and you can click on hard-to-type symbols like integrals and summation signs, rendering what you've clicked and typed instantly into a graphical, clickable form (especially Desmos).

I know I might come off as being lazy (why not just learn LaTex?), but as someone who only need to use snippets of LaTex code and occasionally so, I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me pointers to find such a handy tool.

Related questions:

[What symbolic math software can output latex quickly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338382/what-symbolic-math-software-can-output-latex-quickly)

[Is there a visual editor for LaTeX that allows for graphical editing of the layout elements (like margins, headers etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144589/is-there-a-visual-editor-for-latex-that-allows-for-graphical-editing-of-the-layo/144626#144626)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Check out [WYSIWYG LaTeX editor for maths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57068/wysiwyg-latex-editor-for-maths) for some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GeoGebra:
[image]

where you can insert equations where you want on the working plane. You have an assistant in writing formulas in LaTeX and when you finish copy and paste the latex code generated. See picture above.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) itself does support the exporting of Latex expressions, which addresses my original concern. The following is an example:

1. Type out the mathematical formula you want in Desmos' graphical calculator interface (Figure 1)
2. Highlight the formula with cursor and copy (Ctrl+C / Cmd+C) it like you would copy any regular text. (Figure 1)
3. Paste it onto an Overleaf document, any text editor etc., and you are done! (Figure 2 shows the copied Latex snippet)

Desmos does not advertise this functionality, but I think it is useful for Latex novice like myself who might be more comfortable with using a  WYSIWYG editor to compose complicated Latex functions.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]